# secure scripting within a nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, scripting, extensibility

I want to build a nodejs application that allows users to enter their own JavaScript scripts to interact with my applications API for extensibility purposes.

I want this to be secure; I only want a specific set of objects exposed to the scripts.

Is there a secure way of doing this in node?

Comment: Use a sandbox for this. For example, the [sandbox](http://gf3.github.io/sandbox/) module.

Comment: Thanks but it looks like you can't expose objects to the sandbox? I can't see how to get access to my api from within the sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

The `sandbox` module spawns a child process and runs user scripts in a new context provided by `vm` module. No global variables or node.js methods are accessible in user scripts because the `global` variable is redefined( see line 28, 45-47, file [shovel.js](https://github.com/gf3/sandbox/blob/master/lib/shovel.js)).

If you want to expose some objects and functions, e.g.,

```
var myobj = { x:12, y:12};
var add = function(a, b) { return a + b; };
```

to the user script, e.g.,

```
var b =  100;
myobj.x = add(myobj.x, b);
```

,  prepend the object and the function to the user script and run it by `sandbox` like this:

```
var Sandbox = require('sandbox');
var s = new Sandbox();

s.run('myobj=' + JSON.stringify(myobj) + ';'
         + 'add=' + add.toString() + ';'
         + userscript
         + '; print(myobj);',
        function( output ) {
           console.log(output);
});
```

The output includes the new value of `myobj`:

```
{ result: 'null', console: [ { x: 112, y: 12 } ] }
```

There is a relative discussion: [How restrict access to apis in node.js javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443543/how-restrict-access-to-apis-in-node-js-javascript). But this method is against the rule: **'To prevent accidental global variable leakage, vm.runInNewContext is quite useful, but safely running untrusted code requires a separate process.'** (see http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html)